# Looking for an OAI-PMH provider for OCFL

Tags: linux, open-source, metadata, protocol

I am looking for an [OAI-PMH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Archives_Initiative_Protocol_for_Metadata_Harvesting)¹ provider working on the standardised [Oxford Common File Layout](https://ocfl.io/) (OCFL). It should run under Linux and it should be able to deliver two kinds of Metadata, besides the obligatory [Dublin Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dublin_Core) metadata (oai_dc) it should be able to deliver [CMDI](https://www.clarin.eu/content/component-metadata) metadata.

Open source software is strongly preferred.

Integration with [fedora-commons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_Commons) version 6 is an additional bonus.

Any recommendations?

---

<sub>1:    OAI-PMH is a protocol for metadata harvesting.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The [Open source guide](https://open-source-guide.com/en/Solutions/Applications) suggests Ginco, koha, openflora and pmb.  I would have thought that [e-prints](https://wiki.eprints.org/w/OAI) or [DSpace](https://wiki.lyrasis.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=45548245) have *something* along those lines.

If you find nothing that scratches your itch, there is a [Perl module](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::OAI::Repository) that will help you build what you want.